# MongoDb aggregate query, how to select field from foreign table?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am running a  mongoDb query trying to get the data of my "User" which also include the "CounterParty.name" My aggregate query does get the user back, but does nothing with the fields from Counterparty. I went through the docs several times but cannot seem to figure it out.

My UserSchema

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export type UserDocument = mongoose.Document & {
    email: string;
    password: string;
    status: string;
    name: string;
    counterParty: Schema.Types.ObjectId;
}

const userSchema = new Schema<UserDocument>(
    {
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        status: {
            type: String,
            default: "I am new"
        },
        counterParty: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "CounterParty",
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
)

export const User = model<UserDocument>('User', userSchema);
```

My CounterPartySchema

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export type CounterPartyDocument = mongoose.Document & {
    name: string
}

const counterPartySchema = new Schema<CounterPartyDocument>(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
            trim: true
        },
    },

    { timestamps: true }
)

export const CounterParty = model<CounterPartyDocument>('CounterParty', counterPartySchema);
```

My query code

```
  const user = await User.aggregate<any>([
        { '$match': { email: email } },
        {
            '$lookup': {
                from: 'CounterParty',
                localField: 'counterParty',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'details' 
            }
        }
    ])
    console.log("user", user)
```

My console log statement now returns the user, but nothing to see of the counterParty.

[image]

Any help will be much appreciates! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Your aggregation query looks fine in the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P4TX4INEKZ_) , maybe you dont have such _id: new ObjectId("...786")  in the counterParty collection?